# save many to many relationship - EF

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I've 3 tables: User, Course, UserCourse

how do I save the different courses for a user on table UserCourse using Entity Framework?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, entity framework converts your link table to a direct relationship. That is, you will be able to do this:

```
someUser.Courses.Add(someCourse);
someUser.Courses.Remove(someOtherCourse);

someCourse.Users.Add(someOtherUser);
```

At least if your `UserCourse` table is set up in a way that enables EF to do that. (i.e. only two columns with the two keys of `User` and `Course` set as PK)

Answer (score 0):

UserCourse table should be junction table for EF to understand many-to-many relationship.
For example: UserId (PK), CourseId(PK)

After that you can simply add entities to entity collections.

```
var context = new MyModel();
var user1 = new User { Name = "u1" };
var user2 = new User { Name = "u1" };
context.Users.Add(user1);
context.Users.Add(user2);
var math = new Course { Name = "Math" };
context.Courses.Add(math);
math.Users.Add(user1);
math.Users.Add(user2);
context.SaveChanges();
```

The same logics for adding course to user: `user1.Courses.Add(math);`